# Equivalent list comprhension methods between python and c#

Tags: c#, python, list

Goodmorning guys.

I'm coming from python environment and turning to c# scripting.

Is there a way in c# to simply collect multiple elements from a list as shown?

```
List = []
List.append(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
items = List[2:6]
```

to get

```
c
d
e
f
g
```

Anyone got simple solutions?

Comment: You can look at the using System.Collections.Generic, and use the List<>. List is generic and will take any datatype for instance List<int> my_list = new List<int>(); And you can add to it like my_list.Add(2); And you can use a foreach to go through it. Or something like my_list.ForEach(x=> WriteLine($"x = {x} "));

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved like this, according to your advices:
var Selected = list.Skip(2).Take(5);

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like

```
var items = new [] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
foreach(var x in items.Skip(2).Take(5))
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly equivalent of list comprehension in .NET is LINQ.

```
List newList = list.Skip(2).Take(6);
```

Try this to get your data.

Comment: That actually takes one too many since the python code is doing start and end indexes.